# How can I know the numbers of colors in plt.quiver

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, scatter-plot

I have written a code in matplotlib pyplot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.quiver(x,y,u,v, colour)
```

Here the color is a list of float numbers. My question is how can I know which number represents blue/green etc.

I tried 500 it seems purple, it needs green/blue/yellow, ..etc

I tried random numbers but it was not useful

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `help(plt.quiver)` to quickly read its documentation.

When you call `plt.quiver(x,y,u,v, colour)`, matplotlib uses a colormap to assing a color to each value of `colour`. You can change the colormap with the `cmap` option. In the following example I'll map the magnitude of the vector field to a colormap:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x, y = np.mgrid[-2:2:20j, -2:2:20j]
u = -np.sin(y)
v = np.cos(x)
mag = np.sqrt(u**2 + y**2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
q = ax.quiver(x, y, u, v, mag, cmap="plasma")
ax.set_aspect("equal")
fig.colorbar(q, label="magnitude")
```

[image]

You can also assign a single color to all quivers. In this case you have to set the `color` keyword argument:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
q = ax.quiver(x, y, u, v, color="red")
ax.set_aspect("equal")
```

[image]

You can also assign a specific color to each quiver. In this case, `color` must be a sequence having the same number of elements of `u`. Here I'm going to assign random colors sampled from a specified sequence:

```py
color_set = ["r", "g", "b", "c", "k", "m"]
colors = [random.choice(color_set) for i in range(u.size)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
q = ax.quiver(x, y, u, v, color=colors)
ax.set_aspect("equal")
```

[image]